Controlling the subject of OWL RDF statements in Protégé
Is there a way to force Protégé to output statements about classes of a specific ontology with them being the subject of the statement rather than the object?
For example, instead of:
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person">
    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="#Individual"/>
</rdf:Description>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Individual">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Actor"/>
</owl:Class>

I'd like to see in the file:
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Individual">
    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Actor"/>
</owl:Class>

I understand the two are semantically equivalent, but for educational purposes.
I tried fixing it by hand, but it got reverted on the next load/save cycle.

Technically both OWL axioms are different, i.e. A EquivalentTo B is different from B EquivalentTo A although semantically the same. Given that the implementation in OWL API will probably just collect axioms per subject to get a compact RDF serialization, I doubt this is possible. Also from an educational perspective, I'd say that keeping the order of the axiom is not uninteresting, and then deducing that the whole axiom can be rewritten. Long story short, I don't think there is any option in Protege nor in the underlying OWL API. Syntactically, they are different class equivalence axioms

@UninformedUser more complex than that. Equivalent class axioms have sets as arguments (the spec doesn't describe them as such, but the only coherent interpretation of the specs as they stand are lists with no duplicates and with order unimportant). So, changing the order is a complex undertaking, and libraries can differ. Discussions with various other practitioners came to "best compromise is to sort the elements and always output them in that order" as it's the best way to limit patch sizes on ontologies held in code control systems.

Thank you both for the clarifications. They are informative indeed. I imagine, however, that it would be possible to have an option in authoring software by which, at serialisation time, the ontology in focus would be written out first with all related relationships thereof, sorting its classes and elements alphabetically, and then proceeding to the next ontology.
